# Display records in an excel sheet

Tags: visualforce

I have two objects :
1. Assigned_Task__c object
2. Migration_Report__C object
1 is parent of 2

I have a custom button on Assigned Task object call Generate Migration List
My requirement is when i click on this button all the related records to one particular task are exported to excel sheet.
As you can see below i have this button , so when i click on this i want that the information in the related record comes in an excel sheet.
Can anyone please help me with this code.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

BR,
Shobhit

Answer (score 2):

This sample code will help you

```
<!-- Download_Excel VISUALFORCE Page -->
<apex:page controller="ContactCSV" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#ConatctExport.xls" cache="true">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Export Results" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cs}" var="contact">
            <apex:column value="{!contact.ID}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

```
//Controller - to query the data you need
public class ContactCSV{
    public List<Contact> cs{get; set;}
    public ContactCSV()
    {
    cs = new List<Contact>();
       for (Contact c : [Select id, Name from Contact])
       {       
           cs.add(c);
       }
    }  
}
```

call the Download_Excel vf page on click of button "call Generate Migration List". You may have to use javaScript for this.

Comment: Rohit, thanks for this code but for a particular account record how will i get that like for ex : an account has two contacts so when i click on that button it only gives me contacts for that account only and not contacts in whole salesforce org.How do i get that. ?? thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to do it. But what now i require a list view button where i can check the records and click on the Generate Excel button to generate excel of that records only which i have checked.
Like in my accounts view , i check the accounts and click on an excel button i get data for those checked accounts only.
Any idea how i can do this ? Thanks for your time.